# VERSIONINFO resource not being shown in EXE properties

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, versioninfo

I'm using Delphi 10.0 Seattle on a machine with Windows 10.

We have a system that has several executables. We use the version information via `.rc` file:

```
1 VERSIONINFO
  FILEVERSION 18,2,0,1660
  PRODUCTVERSION 18,2,0,0
  FILEFLAGSMASK VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
  FILEFLAGS (VS_FF_SPECIALBUILD|VS_FF_PRERELEASE)
  FILEOS VOS__WINDOWS32
  FILETYPE VFT_APP
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "041604E4"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", "BLA BLA BLA\0"
            VALUE "FileDescription", "BLA BLABLA - DESCRICAO\0"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "18.2.0.1660\0"
            VALUE "InternalName", "nomexecutavel.exe\0"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright 2018\0"
            VALUE "LegalTrademarks", "BLA BLA BLA é marca registrada\0"
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "nomeexecutavel.exe\0"
            VALUE "ProductName", "nomedoproduto\0"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "18.2.0\0"
            VALUE "SpecialBuild", "Para Homologação\0"
            VALUE "GitRevision", "790d79ee92af023d6beac953072c45b0385df17f\0"
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0416, 1252
    END
END
```

This `.rc` file is compiled through `brcc32.exe`.

In the project file the `.RES` file information generated by `brcc32` is loaded.

```
{$R VersionInfoFactor.res}
```

After I do the build and install on a Windows machine in Portuguese, I can view the version information by right-clicking on the executable, selecting Properties, then Details.

So far, this is nothing new, it shows the data that is informed in the `.rc` file.

[image: Version Ok]

Now, if I install this same executable on a Windows machine in another language, I can no longer view this information.

Would anyone know the cause?

[image: Not Ok has an error of versioninfo]

Comment: Please format the rc text for readability.

Answer (score 8):

Your resource script provides version info for ONLY Portuguese and no other language. So, of course, a non-Portuguese machine won't display anything meaningful.

You need to provide multiple `StringFileInfo` blocks, one for each language you want to support. And you should have a block for US English, which is the fallback when a block for a specific language is not provided.

You should organize the blocks in this order, per [Hierarchical Organization of Resources for Localization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756hydy4.aspx):

- US English
- Neutral cultures
- Specific cultures

On a side note, you don't need to invoke `brcc32.exe` manually. The Delphi compiler can do that for you, if you include the `.rc` filename in the `{$R}` directive:

```
{$R VersionInfoFactor.res VersionInfoFactor.rc}
```